# How do I import a Mobx state tree and reference its values in a Typescript file without a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I want to use values in a MST in a vanilla typescript document. It doesn't have a component, just an object of css values that is referenced in the style tags of elements in other components. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

edit: Here's some code

**Mobx State Tree**

```
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export const BotCSS = types.model({
  chatBackground: types.optional(types.string, '#fff'),
  fontType: types.optional(types.string, 'Open Sans'),
  hoverFillColor: types.optional(types.string, '#306aca'),
  hoverFontColor: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  primaryColor: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1'),
  secondaryColor: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  typingAnimationDots: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1'),
  typingAnimationFill: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  userResponseColor: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1')
})

export type IBotCSS = typeof BotCSS.Type
```

**theme.ts document with theme obj - I want to set mobx values equal to some of these variables**

```
const userMessageBackgroud = `${blue}`
const userMessageBorder = `${blue}`
const userMessageColor = `${white}`

const minimizeboxBackgroud = `${blue}`
const minimizeboxColor = `${white}`

export const theme = {
  AgentBar: {
    Avatar: {
      size: '42px'
    },
    css: {
      backgroundColor: `${secondaryColor}`,
      borderColor: `${avatarBorderColor}`
    }
  },
  AvatarImg: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: 0,
    height: '38px',
    width: '40px'
  }, (...etc)
```

So essentially there are a number of variables at the top of this theme.ts document that are used in the theme object. I want to set the values in mobx equal to the variable declarations at the top of the document

Comment: Are you facing TS type definition issue or the question is about using MST without React? If its the former, try this module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-state-tree-ts. For the latter, MST is generic and could be used outside of React. It'd help if you could share code.

Comment: Hey hazardous, I've updated my answer with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should realize that MobX and MST are completely standalone state management libraries and can perfectly work by themselves, without any component framework.

Secondly you cannot just set the values to properties on the store directly in MST (*first create an instance of the store btw, e.g.: `const botCss = BotCSS.create()`*). You need to define dedicated setters (or [actions](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#actions) in MobX terminology) for that. Something like:

```
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export const BotCSS = types.model({
  chatBackground: types.optional(types.string, '#fff'),
  fontType: types.optional(types.string, 'Open Sans'),
  hoverFillColor: types.optional(types.string, '#306aca'),
  hoverFontColor: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  primaryColor: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1'),
  secondaryColor: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  typingAnimationDots: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1'),
  typingAnimationFill: types.optional(types.string, '#f2f2f2'),
  userResponseColor: types.optional(types.string, '#427ee1')
})
.actions(self => {
  setCss(data) {
    Object.assign(self, data);
  }
})

export const botCss = BotCSS.create() // you might even export the instance itself

export type IBotCSS = typeof BotCSS.Type
```

Then in another module you can import the instance or the Type (*and then create an instance*) and call the setter with new values:

```
import { botCss } from './BotCSS'

botCss.setCss({
   chatBackground: '#ff0000'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you forgot to create a store and for changing the state of your fields in your store, you need to create methods("actions").

Here is a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/7k2noj4v2j)